# Strange bug with wait statement in synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading

An excerpt from Worker.java file:

```
public class Worker extends Thread{

        public void run(){
                // Worker Thread periodically does its job.

       Master.getInstance().decrementNumOfWorkingWorkers();
        // This is the reporting part of the thread.
        // Aimed to wait other threads finish their job.
                synchronized (Master.getInstance().allFinished) {
            while (  Master.getInstance().getNumOfWorkingWorkers() > 0) {
                try {
                    Master.getInstance().allFinished.wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Main.printSync("Worker Thread-" + getPId() + " worked on");
        }
        }
        }
```

This is from Master.Java:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Master extends Timer {

    AllFinished allFinished;
    int day;
    public TimerTask task;
    LinkedList<Worker> Workers;
    private static Master instance = null;
    int numOfWorkingWorkers = 0;

    public class AllFinished
    {

    }

    public class PeriodicIncrement extends TimerTask {
        // Complete this class

        public void run() {

            Main.printSync("Day " + day + ":");
            Main.printSync("Queue: " + TaskQueue.getInstance().ConvertToString());

            day++;
            for (int i = 0; i < Workers.size(); i++) {

                synchronized (Workers.get(i)) {
                    Workers.get(i).notify();
                }
            }

            if (0 == numOfWorkingWorkers) {

                synchronized (allFinished) {
                    allFinished.notifyAll();
                }
                cancel(); // Terminate the timer thread
            }
        }
    }

    private Master(LinkedList<Worker> Workers) {
        super();
        this.task = new PeriodicIncrement();
        day = 0;
        allFinished = new AllFinished();
        this.Workers = Workers;
        numOfWorkingWorkers = this.Workers.size();
        this.schedule(task, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

For a test with 4 worker threads, everything was fine before I added the excerpted part in Worker.java. Then, to report each worker's action after all workers are done, I added that part. Algorithm is very simple. When a worker finishes its job, it checks if there is any job in a TaskQueue and ProductOwner. If there are not any, it breaks its loop and then decrement by 1 active worker threads counter in Master and then calls wait on AllFinished field of Master. run() method of PeriodicIncrement checks this counter and if it is 0 (meaning all workers finished their job), it calls notifyAll() on AllFinished .

Problem is, one sometimes two threads are entering that excerpted code block in Worker.java but remainings never enter so active worker threads counter never decremented to 0 and my program never finishes.
If I just comment out the excerpted part in Worker.java, except finishing and reporting randomly, everything is fine. What I mean is the excerpted part seems to be problematic.

Could you help me to find out?

Comment: Wow, sounds like I'm super rusty on this stuff, and you're right it should release the monitor, and own it before calling `wait`.  I've deleted my answer temporarily because it's misleading. One thing that bugs me is that I don't see you decrementing the number of active workers. Where is it done?

Comment: Added the line that decrementing active workers by one to Worker.java. By the way, I double checked that it really decrements that counter  by printing its value to the console.

Comment: Does it reach 0 though? If you're able to share the whole code I'd be happy to debug with you. I'm bored with confinement haha

Comment: No, it does not reach to 0. run() method of PeriodicIncrement class in Master.java file does not even print the last working day. That implies the last notify() to workers are not sent. But it is sent if I comment out the excerpted part in Worker.java.

Comment: I was gonna ask that, why are you notifying workers in the periodic task and who's waiting on them?

Comment: Periodic Task notifies workers every 100 ms so that worker either continue to their job or seeks a job on task queue.

Comment: Okay thanks. I can't find the problem with the code you have here. Is it possible for you to share the whole code? Maybe not in this question, but in a repo or pastebin if it's too large.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210539/discussion-between-dici-and-mualloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a fun one to debug, after so much time not playing with low-level concurrency primitives. The trick to root-cause this was to use the [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) tool provided by the JDK.

```
╭───courtino ~
╰➤  sudo jstack -l 63978
2020-03-29 21:26:01
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #18 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91491000 nid=0x1803 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Timer-0" #17 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91f36800 nid=0x5903 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000700009aa4000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.ScrumMaster$PeriodicIncrement.run(ScrumMaster.java:42)
- waiting to lock <0x000000076bc70db8> (a com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Programmer-4" #15 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa92cc6800 nid=0x5603 in Object.wait() [0x000070000989e000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.completeTasksUntilNoneAvailable(Programmer.java:230)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.work(Programmer.java:165)
- locked <0x000000076bc71a58> (a com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.run(Programmer.java:241)

"Programmer-3" #14 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa923af800 nid=0x5503 in Object.wait() [0x000070000979b000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.work(Programmer.java:176)
- locked <0x000000076bcc8ac0> (a com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.ScrumMaster$AllFinished)
- locked <0x000000076bc70db8> (a com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.run(Programmer.java:241)

"Programmer-2" #13 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa92c25000 nid=0x3f03 in Object.wait() [0x0000700009698000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.work(Programmer.java:176)
- locked <0x000000076bcc8ac0> (a com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.ScrumMaster$AllFinished)
- locked <0x000000076bc5fca0> (a com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.run(Programmer.java:241)

"Programmer-1" #12 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91fab800 nid=0x4203 in Object.wait() [0x0000700009595000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.completeTasksUntilNoneAvailable(Programmer.java:230)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.work(Programmer.java:165)
- locked <0x000000076bc43c80> (a com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer)
at com.amazon.adnumsmissionmanagerservice.homework.Programmer.run(Programmer.java:241)

"Service Thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91f30800 nid=0x4403 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa9227c000 nid=0x3c03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa9227b000 nid=0x4603 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa92272800 nid=0x4803 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Command Reader" #7 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa9200f000 nid=0x3a03 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Event Helper Thread" #6 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91019800 nid=0x4a03 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" #5 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa9181a000 nid=0x4b07 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa9180d800 nid=0x3603 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91002000 nid=0x3003 in Object.wait() [0x0000700008b77000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x000000076ab08ed8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
- locked <0x000000076ab08ed8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa92006800 nid=0x2e03 in Object.wait() [0x0000700008a74000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x000000076ab06c00> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
- locked <0x000000076ab06c00> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa90843000 nid=0x2d03 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91001800 nid=0x2307 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91801800 nid=0x2a03 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91802000 nid=0x5303 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91802800 nid=0x5203 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffa91357800 nid=0x3d03 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 2236
```

A few observations:

- Thread `Timer-0` (that's your periodic task) is in BLOCKED state, waiting for lock `0x000000076bc70db8`, which is an instance of `Programmer`
- there are 4 programmers:

  - 2 of them are still doing some work and are holding one lock of type `Programmer` (they're actually holding a lock on themselves)
  - the other 2 programmers are done and are holding two locks: one on themselves, and one on `AllFinished`. `Programmer-3` is an example of such thread.

Since the periodic task tries to acquire a lock on `Programmer-3` before notifying it, it has to wait for `Programmer-3` to release the lock on itself, which it can't do because it's waiting for all tasks to complete. Deadlock!

The reason why your programmers are holding a lock on themselves is this:

```
public synchronized void work()
```

This is going to put the entire `work` method into a synchronized block which monitor belongs to `this`. Since the `Programmer` class is stateless and it mostly does work that doesn't interact with other threads, you can actually synchronize a much smaller part of the `work` method. So you have two changes to make:

- remove `synchronized` from the signature of `work`
- synchronize the call to `wait` inside the `work` method:

  ```
  synchronized (this) {
      wait();
  }
  ```

One lesson that it can give is that, when using synchronized block, you always want to synchronize as little code as possible. Anything that doesn't need to be synchronized should be outside of the block, in order to maximize parallelism (everything that happens in the block is sequential), potentially for requiring the lock less often (there might be conditions that allow you to skip the lock acquisition if you put it at the lowest level, so that will reduce the overhead of synchronization), and in some cases like this one, avoiding deadlocks.